# How can I implement switch without code redundancy?

Tags: c#

I have the following switch:

```
switch (triggerTypeId) {
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContract: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContractEnd: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateHours: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateInterview: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateJobApplication: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistration: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistrationWeb: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateSalary: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    break;
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
    break;
}
```

How can I implement switch without code redundancy?
I need operation `list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);` is all cases and in 1 case I need additional operation `list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);`

I'va tried so far

```
switch (triggerTypeId) {
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked:
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
        break;
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContract:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContractEnd:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateHours:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateInterview:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateJobApplication:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistration:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistrationWeb:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateSalary:
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
        break;
}
```

but I hope it can be improved. I can't use if only for last case because I have a many `triggerType` and only for a few I need to add `SendThisQuestion` and only for one of few I need to add `WeeksWorked`. Please give me some advices

Comment: You can use a fallthrough on your case, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/174223/592182) but it's debatable if this is easier to read than your current solution.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: "I need operation `list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);` is all cases" - Do you mean that you add that to the list irregardless of the type? If so why not just always add that and have an `if` checking whether or not you should have `list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);` too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of approaches.

Option 1, use a fall through from one case to the next:

```
switch (triggerTypeId) {
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked:
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
        goto case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContract;

    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContract:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContractEnd:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateHours:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateInterview:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateJobApplication:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistration:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistrationWeb:
    case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateSalary:
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
        break;
}
```

Option 2, put the items in a collection and use that to drive processing:

```
List<int> _sendQuestionRequired = new List<int> {
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContract,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateContractEnd,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateHours,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateInterview,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateJobApplication,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistration,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateRegistrationWeb,
                Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateSalary};

if(triggerTypeId == Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked) {
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
}
if(_sendQuestionRequired.Contains(triggerTypeId)) {
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
}
```

As pointed out by @SimonForsberg in the comments, a `HashSet` would be a more efficient collection choice for the above code, however as you've stated in your comment on @EricLippert's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/129133/4203) that you're constrained to .Net 2.0, this might not be an option for you as it was introduced in version 3.5.  [Depending on what drives the version constraint you may be able to use it anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/687042/592182).

Whether or not either approach is better is somewhat subjective and depends on the rest of your code which you haven't included.

Comment: `_sendQuestionRequired` would be benificial to use as a `Set` instead of a List.

Comment: @SimonForsberg what do you mean? Could you please explain? You mean `HashSet<T>`?

Comment: @SimonForsberg That's a good point, I'll update it when I get to a keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

1) For me the biggest impediment to readability in your code is the fully-qualified names.  Use a combination of `using` and, in C# 6, `using static` directives to reduce the visual clutter in your code:

```
var questionId = SendThisQuestion.Id;
var weeksWorkedId = WeeksWorked.Id;
switch (triggerTypeId) {
    case CandidateWeeksWorked:
        list.Add(questionId);
        list.Add(weeksWorkedId);
        break;
    case CandidateContract:
    case CandidateContractEnd:
    case CandidateHours:
    case CandidateInterview:
    case CandidateJobApplication:
    case CandidateRegistration:
    case CandidateRegistrationWeb:
    case CandidateSalary:
        list.Add(questionId);
        break;
}
```

That is so much easier on the eyes.

2) Consider extracting this to a method:

```
IEnumerable<ID> GetIds(ID triggerTypeId) 
{ 
  var questionId = SendThisQuestion.Id;
  var weeksWorkedId = WeeksWorked.Id;
  switch (triggerTypeId) {
    case CandidateWeeksWorked:
        yield return questionId;
        yield return weeksWorkedId;
        break;
    case CandidateContract:
    case CandidateContractEnd:
    case CandidateHours:
    case CandidateInterview:
    case CandidateJobApplication:
    case CandidateRegistration:
    case CandidateRegistrationWeb:
    case CandidateSalary:
        yield return questionId;
        break;
}
```

And now you can simply say:

```
list.AddRange(GetIds(triggerTypeId));
```

Extracting the logic to a method has many nice characteristics:

- It's easier to read.
- There's one place to change the code if you need to update the logic.
- If you need the list of IDs in multiple places, you have a method you can call to get it.
- The new method does not mutate a list; it returns a sequence. You can do whatever you want with that sequence; it doesn't have to be added to a list. It could be sorted or searched or combined with other sequences, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks but 1) I don't use C#6 and I can't use `using` with static class. 2)   Of course my code already in method but I asked only about switch, so I showed here only switch. In your excample I see almost the  same switch as in my question except long name of constants. I use C# 2.0 so I your login for method with yield not supported

Comment: @MegaTron: Why are you using a version of C# that is **over ten years out of date**?  There is a *lot* of good stuff added in the last ten years; use it!

Comment: C# 2.0 using my company where I work. It's not my choose.

Comment: @MegaTron: In the future you might want to mention that restriction before you ask for code improvements. Many of those improvements will involve features that were designed after *Revenge of the Sith* left theaters.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this?

```
list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
switch (triggerTypeId) {
case Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked: 
    list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

The above would add `SendThisQuestion.Id` in all cases and `WeeksWorked.Id` also in the `CandidateWeaksWorked` case. Wouldn't it?

Comment: No.  I have a many triggerType but not all. And in this case why do not use `if`?

Comment: I suggest you update your code then to reflect that.

Comment: That information is in my question. Please look again

Comment: Special for you:  "I have a many triggerType and only for a few I need to add SendThisQuestion and only for one of few I need to add WeeksWorked"

Answer (score -1):

I think breaking this into pieces migth be helpfull:

```
private static bool ShoudAddQuestion(Dom.Survey.TriggerType triggerType)
{
    return (triggerType == YOURTYPE1 || triggerType == YOURTYPE2 || ...);
}

public void YourFunction(Dom.Survey.TriggerType triggerTypeId, ...)
{
    ...    
    if (ShoudAddQuestion(triggerTypeId))
    {
        list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.SendThisQuestion.Id);
        if (triggerTypeId.Equals(Dom.Survey.TriggerType.CandidateWeeksWorked))
        {
            list.Add(Dom.Survey.Rule.WeeksWorked.Id);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

On thing I have learned (and learned on codereview) is you have to break code to very specifics operations. The piece of code you have exposed shoud do what ? Add something to a list or check if it should be add to a list ?

For the comment that said using a HashSet is better that using a list, I will let you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150750/hashset-vs-list-performance) for more informations.